# end measure process of HX711 with Door Lock magnetic sensor

Tags: sensors

I'm doing a program that starts the measuring process, using an HX711 when the door lock magnetic sensor spits and, when ends the measuring process when the door lock magnetic sensor joins.

```
if (analogRead(A0) > 50){
    scale.power_up();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 4);
    lcd.print("Peso: ");
    lcd.print(scale.get_units(), 3);
    Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 3);
    lcd.print(" kg");
    Serial.print("\t");   

    myRTC.updateTime();
    Serial.print(myRTC.dayofmonth);                                                                     
    Serial.print("/");                                                                                      
    Serial.print(myRTC.month);                                                                              
    Serial.print("/");                                                                                      
    Serial.print(myRTC.year);                                                                              
    Serial.print("  ");                                                                                     
    Serial.print(myRTC.hours);                                                                              
    Serial.print(":");                                                                                      
    Serial.print(myRTC.minutes);                                                                            
    Serial.println("");
    delay(3250);
    digitalWrite(pinR1, LOW);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    delay(2000);

    if( analogRead(A0) < 50){
    lcd.print("   Peso Registado   ");
    delay(3500);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(" O planeta agradece ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
    lcd.print("    a sua ajuda!    ");
    delay(3000);
    lcd.clear();
    }  

    lcd.print("------TI-Trash------");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1); 
    myRTC.updateTime();     
    lcd.print("   ");
    lcd.print(myRTC.dayofmonth); 
    lcd.print("/");                                                                                                                                                   
    lcd.print(myRTC.month);                                                                             
    lcd.print("/");                                                                                     
    lcd.print(myRTC.year);                                                                              
    lcd.print("  ");                                                                                   
    lcd.print(myRTC.hours);                                                                            
    lcd.print(":");                                                                                     
    lcd.print(myRTC.minutes);                                                                                                                                                
    lcd.setCursor(0, 4);
    lcd.print("LOADING...");
    delay(2500);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 4);
    lcd.print(">APROXIME SEU CARTAO");
    }
 }
```

The problem is that I don't know how can I control the end of the measuring process because the process ends after a few seconds.

How can I controll the end of the measuring process

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable for the state of the door. If state of the door is `closed` and the sensor shows that the door is open that is the moment where the you update the state of the door to `open` and start to measure. When the door state is `open` and the sensor shows that it is closed that is the moment when you change the state of the door to `closed` and stop measure.

Comment: Can you help me with examples of the code you're talking about?